# Jmeter exclude thread group from summary result report

Tags: jmeter

is there a way to exclude thread group from summary report results. I have several threads group for which I need result in summary report. After summary report is generated in given location path I have a tear down thread group with jdbc request that save the report un database. I neeto exclude this teardown thread group to be not processed and saved in the report.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1. Use [Filter Results tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)
2. Add [JSR223 Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a direct child of the tearDown Thread Group and put the following code there:

   ```
   prev.setIgnore()
   ```
3. If you're using [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) there is [`jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#saveservice_requirements) where you can specify which transactions you would like to see in the report

Comment: Is this approaches garantee that  all threads are completed?

Comment: None of them will stop your test prematurely